Unable to achieve login persistence in React Native
I'm currently working on my first React Native project and am running into some issues with firebase's user authentication persistence. My connection to firebase's authentication services is completely fine; users are able to sign up and log into the app as they wish. What I'm unable to do is to allow for login persistence between sessions.
I was told that I shouldn't use AsyncStorage to store user login details, but I continue to receive a warning message saying the following...
You are initializing Firebase Auth for React Native without providing
AsyncStorage. Auth state will default to memory persistence and will not
persist between sessions. In order to persist auth state, install the package
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" and provide it to
initializeAuth:
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
});

Here is my App.tsx:
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React, { Children, createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import { globalStyles } from './../fields/src/styles/global';
import Map from './src/screens/Map';
import { Image } from 'react-native-reanimated/lib/typescript/Animated';
import SoccerIcon from './src/assets/svg/SoccerIcon';
import CommunityIcon from './src/assets/svg/CommunityIcon';
import ProfileIcon from './src/assets/svg/ProfileIcon';
import MessageIcon from './src/assets/svg/MessageIcon';
import EventScreen from './src/screens/tabs/EventScreen';
import CommunityScreen from './src/screens/tabs/CommunityScreen';
import MessageScreen from './src/screens/tabs/MessageScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/screens/tabs/ProfileScreen';
import Login from './src/screens/Login';
import Signup from './src/screens/Signup';
import COLORS from './src/assets/colors';
import { auth } from './firebase';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  title: string;
}>;

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AuthenticatedUserContext = createContext({});

// this context provides its children the stateful value of user and the stateful function of setUser
const AuthenticatedUserProvider = ({children} : { children: any}) => { // explicitly state that children can take any type
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // by default, the user's value is set to null.
  // all children wrapped in the AuthenticatedUserProvider will be provided the user value as well as the setUser function
  return (
    <AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}> 
      {children} 
    </AuthenticatedUserContext.Provider>
  );
};

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Events" // tab navigator will initially route to the events screen
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({

        tabBarStyle: {
          position: 'absolute',
          height: 65,
          paddingBottom:10
        },

        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          marginTop: -10
        },

        // dynamically choose icons and allow for color fill
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          let IconComponent;

          if (route.name === 'Events') {
            IconComponent = SoccerIcon;
          } else if (route.name === 'Community') {
            IconComponent = CommunityIcon;
          } else if (route.name === 'Message') {
            IconComponent = MessageIcon;
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            IconComponent = ProfileIcon;
          }

          return <IconComponent color={focused ? COLORS.GREEN : COLORS.BLACK} />;
        },
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Events"
        component={EventScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.GREEN,
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: COLORS.BLACK,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Community"
        component={CommunityScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.GREEN,
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: COLORS.BLACK,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Message"
        component={MessageScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.GREEN,
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: COLORS.BLACK,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.GREEN,
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: COLORS.BLACK,
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

function AppStack () {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Launch'>
      <Stack.Screen name="Launch" component={TabNavigator} options={{headerShown: false}}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function AuthStack () {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function RootNavigator () {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext); // the error 'Property 'user' does not exist on type '{}' should be expected, because these variables have null value by default
  const {loading, setLoading} = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => { 
    // onAuthStateChanged returns an unsubscriber
    // assign unsubscribeAuth the subscription
    const unsubscribeAuth = onAuthStateChanged( 
      auth,
      async authenticatedUser => {
        authenticatedUser ? setUser(authenticatedUser) : setUser(null);  // if there is an authenticated user, the AuthenticatedUserContext will be set to authenticatedUser
        setLoading(false);
      }
    );
    return () => unsubscribeAuth() // unsubscribe from the auth listener, saving us from making unneccesary queries to the firebase
  }, [user]);

  if(loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    // if a user exists, navigate to the AppStack, else navigate to AuthStack
    <NavigationContainer> 
      { user ? <AppStack></AppStack> : <AuthStack></AuthStack>}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  // the root navigator is wrapped in the AuthenticatedUserContext.
  return (
    <AuthenticatedUserProvider> 
      <RootNavigator></RootNavigator>
    </AuthenticatedUserProvider>
  )
}

And here is my login.js:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Image, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, Alert } from "react-native";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, setPersistence, inMemoryPersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../../firebase";
import COLORS from "../assets/colors";
const img = require("../assets/images/green-soccer.jpg");

export default function Login({ navigation }) {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState(""); // email will persist across multiple renders
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(""); // password will persist across multiple renders
    
    const onHandleLogin = () => {
      if (email !== "" && password !== "") {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
          .then(() => console.log("Login success"))
          .catch((err) => Alert.alert("Login error", err.message));
      }
    };
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={img} style={styles.backImage}></Image>
        <View style={styles.whiteSheet} />
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.form}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Log In</Text>
           <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Enter email"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          textContentType="emailAddress"
          autoFocus={true}
          value={email}
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Enter password"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          textContentType="password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onHandleLogin}>
          <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#fff', fontSize: 18}}> Log In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{marginTop: 20, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'gray', fontWeight: '600', fontSize: 14}}>Don't have an account? </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signup")}>
            <Text style={{color: COLORS.GREEN, fontWeight: '600', fontSize: 14}}> Sign Up</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      </View>
    );

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: "#fff",
},
title: {
fontSize: 36,
fontWeight: 'bold',
color: COLORS.GREEN,
alignSelf: "center",
paddingBottom: 24,
},
input: {
backgroundColor: "#F6F7FB",
height: 58,
marginBottom: 20,
fontSize: 16,
borderRadius: 10,
padding: 12,
},
backImage: {
width: "100%",
height: 200,
position: "absolute",
top: 0,
resizeMode: 'cover',
},
whiteSheet: {
width: '100%',
height: '82.5%',
position: "absolute",
bottom: 0,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
borderTopLeftRadius: 50
},
form: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
marginHorizontal: 30,
},
button: {
backgroundColor: COLORS.GREEN,
height: 58,
borderRadius: 10,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
marginTop: 40,
},
});

I suspected that it had something to do with my initializing of the user with a null value, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I've tried refactoring my code as well, but that didn't lead to anything either.
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated :)


Add async storage. You have to be careful what you store, but just in the same way you’d need to on a website. The sdk will handle things under the hood and you’ll be fine.
